# How can I manage multiple related Android projects in one git repo

Tags: android, git, version-control

So I'm building multiple apps based off the same Android code, but the problem is I'm not sure how I can manage these. If I have multiple branches I don't want the master branch to overwrite the manifest.xml (and some of the other specific files for that project) of the other project. is there a way to lock cretin files in another branch from being overwritten on Merge? or a way to selectively merge files?

I'm using Git as my source control. there are only maybe 10 or so files that change between apps... mostly having to do with theme. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Also let me know if this question type does not belong on Stack Overflow. I'll be happy to move it.

Comment: If you're using gradle you can have different flavors for different apps which share the same code.. in that case you won't have to rely on the repository. But if your not using gradle, im affraid @Martin Konecny's answer is the correct approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the "root" branch that all of your projects branch off from is `master`, and that you branch a specific app project into branch `project_a`.

If you change the manifest file in branch `project_a`, and then do `git merge master`, then you won't have any issues (nothing will change in your `project_a` branch).

`merge` doesnt simply copy all differences from another branch over. It also looks into other factors like the timestamp of the commit.

For example:

```
cd git-test
git init
echo "hello" > manifest.txt
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

git checkout -b project_a
echo "world" > manifest.txt 
git commit -am "change in project branch"
git merge master #  no effect
```

The last line has no effect because the change to the manifest.txt in `project_a` branch is newer than the change to manifest.txt in the `master` branch.